# Using chart found in form 2

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use chart to show some graphics.
I have two Forms (Form1 and Form2 ).The chart is located in Form2, but I want to write the code in Form1, like let's say in Form1 when I click on GRAPHIC button will show me chart in Form2.
The problem is when I write the code in Form1, it give me error saying the name of the chart(which is found in Form2) not found in Form1. How can I solve this problem.
This is part of my code:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Graphic
    {
        Form2 fr2 = new Form2(A );
        this.Hide();
        fr2.ShowDialog();
        chart1.series["student's grad"].Points.Addxy("A", A);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
public Form2(object A)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   chart1.series["student's grad"].Points.Addxy("A", A);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things that I can see, the first is that you are using `ShowDialog` which will run fr2 as a Modal Dialog box which will Block Form1 until you close fr2, the second is that since you are wanting to access the Chart in frm2 you would either need to use a Public Property/Method or make your Chart's Visibility Public. I would recommend that you use a `Property` or a Public Method that way you are keeping the internals of your second Form Hidden.

Something like this might work for you:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 fr2 = new Form2();
        this.Hide();
        fr2.AddPoint("student's grad", new Point( 0,0));
        fr2.ShowDialog();
    }
}


public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void AddPoint( string series, Point chartPoint)
    {
        chart1.Series["student's grad"].Points.AddXY(chartPoint.X, chartPoint.Y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir... I'll do that
Thank a lot